# Trouble with HTML Contact Form PHP Not Sending Emails to Gmail

Tags: php, html, forms, email, server

I've created a simple contact form that should be sending emails via php to me however, when I attempt to send/submit the form I continue to get the "message failed" output and have confirmed nothing is coming to my gmail inbox.

I have gone into my host server (heartland) and tried updating the Php.ini Port to (25 and 2525) and changed my SMTP to the host mail server. I've checked my error log and resolved any errors reported on it. I'm unsure if the issue lies within my host server or my actual php/form code.

**Form Code**

```html
<h2>Contact Form</h2>
<form id="contactForm" method="POST" action="formHandler.php">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" required data-error="Please enter your name">
        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Email" id="email" class="form-control" name="email" required data-error="Please enter your email">
        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Subject" id="msg_subject" class="form-control" required data-error="Please enter your subject">
        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <textarea class="form-control" id="message" name="message" placeholder="Your Message" rows="5" data-error="Write your message" required></textarea>
        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="submit-button">
        <button class="btn btn-common" id="submit" type="submit" value="submit" target="_blank">Send Message</button>
        <div id="msgSubmit" class="h3 text-center hidden"></div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

**PHP  Code**

```html
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$to = "myemail@gmail.com";
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$formcontent=" From: $name \n Email: $email \n Message: $message";

$subject = "Contact Form";

$mailheader = "From: $email \r \n";

mail($to, $mailheader, $subject, $formcontent);

echo "<p>Thank you for contacting me!</p>";
echo "<p>I will reply to your inquiry in 24-48 business hours.</p>";
echo "<a href='form.html' style='text-decoration:none;color:#ff0099;'> Return Home</a>";

} 
else{
    echo "<p> Message Failed to Send.</p>";
  echo "<a href='form.html' style='text-decoration:none;color:#ff0099;'> Return Home</a>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change tag `button` to `input`

```
<input class="btn btn-common" id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Send Message">
```

Because tag `button` doesn't send any value and name. And this condition `isset($_POST['submit'])` always will give `false`

Or you can change condition

Comment: Thank you! I did go in and correct that- however, I still find I'm getting a failure to send output.

Comment: @newbie_csharp123 Do you still get message `Message Failed to Send` ?

Comment: Yes, that is the message I get.

Comment: @newbie_csharp123 show what output  `var_dump($_POST['submit'])` before main `if`

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in /home/www/mywebsite.com/formHandler.php on line 54

this is referring to the semi color right after my "to" email line:
$to = "myemail@gmail.com";

Comment: After running a simple mail test looks like it might be a web host provider issue- I'm reaching out to them for help.-- thank you for helping me!

Comment: @newbie_csharp123 u a welcome

Answer (score 0):

Can you send emails with the current configuration your using for this script on another app? Some providers block "unsecure" connections. If you cant send emails with the current smtp config on another app, then the problem is not your script.

Another thing: Have you tried with single quotes in
$to = 'myemail@gmail.com';